# Codeigniter: Inserting a row with foreign keys using active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, psql

How can I write the below SQL query in codeigniter using active records?

`INSERT INTO messages VALUES (default, 'Testing working 2', (SELECT id from users WHERE username ='0767000000'),
(SELECT group_code from groups WHERE group_code = 654321), default ) ;`

Or is there a best way to do this? 
(Am new in PHP and CI MVC)

Answer (score 1):

**For complex queries, you can execute custom query in codeigniter like this :**

```
$sql = "Your query";

$this->db->query($sql);
```

Check last executed query by using following code :

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
```